# How to construct a TimeGrouper with a DateOffset?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to programatically construct a pandas `TimeGrouper`. A quick look at the code shows that the `freq` parameter of the `TimeGrouper`'s `__init__` method gets converted into a `DateOffset` by the `to_offset()` function. Furthermore, `to_offset()` checks whether its parameter is an instance of `DateOffset` and if true, returns it.

So, this code should work:

```
import pandas as pd
period = 'minute'
value = 10
time_grouper = pd.TimeGrouper(pd.DateOffset(**{period:value}))
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.py", line 45, in __init__
    rule = self.freq.rule_code
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\offsets.py", line 217, in rule_code
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

I'm using version **0.12.0** of pandas.

What am I missing to get working instances of `DateOffset` and `TimeGrouper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to construct an offset explicity (though you can if you want), simply
passing '10T' is enough (this is what `to_offset` does, converts it to an offset object)`. Furthermore, you rarely need to explicity construct a`TimeGrouper`(and in 0.14.0, releasing shorty), you don't need to at all. You generally just`resample``

```
In [5]: pd.offsets.Minute('10')
Out[5]: <10 * Minutes>

In [6]: pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10T')
Out[6]: <pandas.tseries.resample.TimeGrouper at 0x3faab90>

In [7]: pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10T').freq
Out[7]: <10 * Minutes>

In [8]: pd.TimeGrouper(freq=pd.offsets.Minute('10')).freq
Out[8]: <10 * Minutes>
```

You could also do this:

```
In [1]: values = { 'minute' : 10, 'hour' : 5 }

In [3]: [ getattr(pd.offsets,k.capitalize())(v) for k,v in values.items() ]
Out[3]: [<5 * Hours>, <10 * Minutes>]
```

Or this (by specifying a tuple)

```
In [3]: pd.TimeGrouper(freq=(5,'Min')).freq
Out[3]: <5 * Minutes>

In [4]: pd.TimeGrouper(freq=(10,'H')).freq
Out[4]: <10 * Hours>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, given that I have the `period` and `value` parameters, I would have to do something like the following to construct a `TimeGrouper`:

    if period == 'minute':
        offset_alias = '{}Min'.format(value)
    elif period == 'hour':
        offset_alias = '{}h'.format(value)
    time_grouper = pd.TimeGrouper(offset_alias)

which I would want to avoid. Why does `pd.DateOffset(**{period:value})` produce and invalid instance?

Comment: well, that is not a very pythonic interface to have a class factory from an instance; it could be done but IMHO would be unexpected and not very useful.

Comment: Just saw your updated solution. Thanks, that is more flexible.

Comment: It may not be pythonic, but IMHO it is easy to read; and if the API allows it, my initial approach should have worked.

Comment: their is another way, specify a tuple (see above); I guess you could put forth an enhancement to add a { name : value } to be accepted as well (as the freq parameter)

Comment: Most of the options above are 'shorthands' to explicityly creating the DateOffset object used internally. Maybe my code is incorrectly creating a DateOffset object and that is why it breaks; if not it may be a bug.

Comment: ``DateOffset`` is normally not created by the user directly; you use a string shorthand or create a *specific* DateOffset sub-class. You want a factory; which is unpythonic to do from an instance. Their are plenty of ways to do it as I have given.